# Wordpress - How to create a one pager and show pages underneath?

Tags: wordpress

I have created two different pages in WP which are using two different templates that I have created. I now want to create a third page in which those two pages are listed underneath each other, but should have the design of the two other templates.

How do I have to create this third template file? If I get the two pages with the get_children() function, I have to reproduce the templates for these two different children pages in my third template. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: You can reuse template files with [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)

Comment: Yes, but this won't help me, because I want to have the whole page which uses a certain template to be displayed...and I do not have the possibility to pass data to "get_template_part".